# overflow-x link should center on next line

Tags: html, css

How do I make that possible if Link that overflow-x should center on next line on resizing the browser window?
I simply want that every link which overflows on x-axis is placed centered on next line.

```css
/* CSS */
.upper-nav-bar ul {
    border: 1px solid black;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    margin-left: 6%;
    margin-right: 6%;
    padding-left: 6%;
    padding-right: 6%;
}

.upper-nav-bar ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.upper-nav-bar ul a {
    font-size: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #c4cccc;
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 9px;
    padding-left: 9px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="upper-nav-bar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#!">EPAPER</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">LIVE TV</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">DAWNNEWS URDU</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">IMAGES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">EVENTS / SUPPLEMENTS</a></li>
    <li id="last-child"><a href="#!">OBITUARIES</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
.upper-nav-bar ul {
    text-align: center;
   //other codes...
}
```

```css
    .upper-nav-bar ul {
    border: 1px solid black;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    margin-left: 6%;
    margin-right: 6%;
    padding-left: 6%;
    padding-right: 6%;
    text-align: center;
    }

    .upper-nav-bar ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    }

    .upper-nav-bar ul a {
    font-size: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #c4cccc;
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 9px;
    padding-left: 9px;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="upper-nav-bar">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#!">EPAPER</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">LIVE TV</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">DAWNNEWS URDU</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">IMAGES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">EVENTS / SUPPLEMENTS</a></li>
        <li id="last-child"><a href="#!">OBITUARIES</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center all link then

```css
    /* CSS */
    .upper-nav-bar ul {
    border: 1px solid black;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    margin-left: 6%;
    margin-right: 6%;
    padding-left: 6%;
    padding-right: 6%;
    }

   .upper-nav-bar ul li {
   display: inline-block;
    }
   ul{
   text-align: center;
   }

    .upper-nav-bar ul a {
    font-size: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #c4cccc;
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 9px;
    padding-left: 9px;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
```

```html
<div class="upper-nav-bar">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#!">EPAPER</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">LIVE TV</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">DAWNNEWS URDU</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">IMAGES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">EVENTS / SUPPLEMENTS</a></li>
        <li id="last-child"><a href="#!">OBITUARIES</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply `text-align: center` to the `ul` tag.

I also used `margin` and `padding` [shorthand styling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties#Margin_and_Padding_Properties). It helps shorten the code significantly and, in my opinion, improves readability.

```css
/* CSS */
.upper-nav-bar ul {
  border: 1px solid black;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 6%;
  padding: 0 6%;
  text-align: center;
}

.upper-nav-bar ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.upper-nav-bar ul a {
  font-size: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #c4cccc;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 9px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="upper-nav-bar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#!">EPAPER</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">LIVE TV</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">DAWNNEWS URDU</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">IMAGES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">EVENTS / SUPPLEMENTS</a></li>
    <li id="last-child"><a href="#!">OBITUARIES</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: why? you copy my answer!

Comment: @ehsan I didn't. I was just posting the same thing as you :)

Comment: What is the reason,there are several similar answers? it is not correct.